# jQuery plugin call function from function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, call

How can I call a function of jQuery plugin from inside of the same object. I use exact suggested solution http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Plugin_Methods. From external code I can call this way:

```
$('div').tooltip("myMethod", an_attr);
```

But how can I call the same from inside especially form event when 'this' is not the object of plugin.

```
var methods = {
    var $this = $(this);
    init : function( options ) {
        $this.click(function(){
            $this.fn2("myMethod", an_attr); //is it right way?

        });
    },
    fn2 : function() {
        //but how can I call the myMethod. here ?
    },
    myMethod : function() {...
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap `this` in `$()`, it's already a jQuery object.

Comment: Could you elaborate what `this` should be and what you want to call, in what order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `fn2` to invoke `myMethod` you could do the following:

```
...
fn2: function() {
  methods.myMethod();
}
...
```

To be sure that `myMethod` has the same context as all of the others, you could do:

```
...
fn2: function() {
  methods.myMethod.call(this);
}
...
```

More details on `call()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

A JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/edslocombe/UGbYz/).

Comment: thank you, it works fine. Is there any way to reach DOM node without sending this by the 'call'.

Comment: I suppose one answer might be to change each of your functions in `methods` to always require the jQuery object are the first parameter, and change the line `methods[method].apply(this, ...)` to ensure the first argument is also `this` (the jQuery object), then you have the collection of DOM nodes available to you using [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). An alternative is to use [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)...